# Overflow icon is not coming the Actionbar of ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am new to Android. I am trying to use Actionbarsherlock in my application. I tried the following code in the onCreateOptionsMenu :

```
  menu.add("Save").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.add("Edit").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.add("Clear").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.add("Refresh").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
  menu.add("Save all").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

But i am not getting the overflow icon in the actionbar. I understood its a silly mistake. But i couldn't find where it is. Please help me to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` I think none of the Menu Items go in to OverFlow.

Also, If the device has a **hardware menu button**, then the extra icons will not go in to overflow, instead you can access them using the menu button.

Comment: if i can't use the MenuItem in overflow, What else can be added in Overflow? and how to do it? Consider there is no hardware menu button.

Comment: If you don't have a hardware menu button on the device, and want to have extra menu items in the overflow menu, use `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM`

Comment: Thank you. It works. But if i want extra Items to be placed in the Overflow irrespective of the device, is there any way to attain this?